# Wordpress - Get higher hierarchy posts

Tags: php, wordpress, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a menu based on higher hierarchy posts from a custom post type.
The thing is, that I can't find the way to filter hierarchy with get_posts function.

This is what I have so far...

```
                  <?php 
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby'          => 'post_date',
                        'order'            => 'DESC',
                        'post_type'        => 'pb_progproy',
                        'post_status'      => 'publish',
                        'suppress_filters' => true 
                    );
                    $posts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach( $posts as $post ){
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php } ?>
```

I know that this will give me all posts regardless of it's hierarchy. What I need is just the ones with higher hierarchy.

Any ideas?

---

Let's figure this posts structure..

```
Post 1
   Post A
   Post B
Post 2
```

I just want Post 1 and Post 2 to be returned from get_posts function. Is there a way?

Comment: what do you mean with 'hierarchy'? [WP Posts filters are the ones available here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage). Are you talking about "post_parent"?

Comment: Just added an example

Comment: my question is how are you handling this hierarchy. Are you using the "post_parent" relationship?

Comment: Yes, I've selected Post 1 as Post a's and Post b's parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the parent-child hierarchy, you can get parent posts filtering posts where "post_parent = 0"

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'pb_progproy',
    'post_parent'      => 0
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

You can read [more about post filters here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Default_Usage).

Comment: That was it. Thanks Paulo